# Why do I need to re-add ssh keys on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu. I've created a non-root user (not sure if that plays into the issue or not). I can ssh into the droplet with my local identity, and on the server I have an distinct ssh key generated and added to github to pull repository updates. It works, but whenever I connect to the server anew I need to run:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key
$ git ...
```

Before the key is loaded. Why is the key not permanently added and how can I make it so I don't need to load the key after each login?

Comment: Try by adding : `AddKeysToAgent yes` in your `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Because you start a new agent instance.

Comment: Normally, it only asks you for the key passphrase once you are connected to your server. - It should work without adding your key in the ssh agent. - On your local computer, you should maybe have something like `gnome-keyring` / `seahorse` ? This method permits to load your keys inside : ~/.ssh/ at startup directly in `ssh-agent`.

Comment: @hidigoudi no idea what you are talking about passphrases? not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the subject of the post
[How to permanently add a private key with ssh-add on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/how-to-permanently-add-a-private-key-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu)

The answer by daminetreg says :

> A solution would be to force the key files to be kept permanently, by
> adding them in your `~/.ssh/config` file:
>
> ```
> IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitHubKey
> IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_buhlServer
> ```
>
> If you do not have a 'config' file in the ~/.ssh directory, then you
> should create one. It does not need root rights, so simply:
>
> ```
> nano ~/.ssh/config
> ```
>
> ...and enter the lines above as per your requirements.
>
> For this to work the file needs to have chmod 600. You can use the
> command `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`.
>
> If you want all users on the computer to use the key put these lines
> into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and the key in a folder accessible to all.
>
> Additionally if you want to set the key specific to one host, you can
> do the following in your ~/.ssh/config :
>
> ```
> Host github.com
>     User git
>     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/githubKey
> ```
>
> This has the advantage when you have many identities that a server
> doesn't reject you because you tried the wrong identities first. Only
> the specific identity will be tried.

Comment: Thanks. I had a `.ssh/config` and Host definition, but explicitly listing the `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/...` at the beginning of the config file did the trick.